# Change export to PDF name set to cell value with Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I am working on a sheet that exports the sheet by pressing a button on said sheet.
The export itself works, however the name of the file is still wrong (file name is set to "Range" every time.)

Sheet name = Factuur

Cell with the value to which the name of the file has to be set to: G1

Good to know (in case it matters) is that G1 contains a formula to determine the cell value (name for the document.)

```
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Save PDF", functionName:"generatePdf"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Export', submenu);
}

function generatePdf() {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var titleName = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("G1")
  var pdfName = titleName;

  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true) ;
}
```

Would love to see ideas on how to fix this problem so the file name is set to the value of the cell on G2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, the file is created with `var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);`. Here, `pdfName` is used as the filename. When I saw the origin of `pdfName`, it seemed that `var pdfName = titleName;` and `var titleName = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("G1")`. This is the Class Range object. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to use the value of "G1" of `sourceSpreadsheet` as the filename. Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var titleName = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("G1")
```

#### To:

```
var titleName = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
```

or

```
var titleName = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("G1").getDisplayValue();
```

- By this modification, the cell value is used.

Comment: Worked like a charm, used your first line. Tried many attempts and even something similar to what you suggested haha.